# Como é uma forma ágil de adicionar e remover comentários de códigos no VIM?

Tags: vim, comentários

Não quero remover a linha inteira de código no VIM, o que eu quero é trabalhar com os códigos de comentário. Tenho 3 casos destintos:

Comentários com que se abrem e fecham (normalmente multiplas linhas):

```
/* doSomething(); */
```

Comentários com 2 caracteres na linha de código (um por linha):

```
// doSomething();
```

E comentários com apenas 1 caractere no inicio (um por linha):

```
# doSomething();
```

Gostaria de saber uma forma ágil de adicionar e remover esses tipos de comentários no VIM, de forma que se aplique apenas a linhas seletivas do código e não a todo o arquivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro usar o plugin [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), que provê atalhos únicos para comentar/descomentar em várias linguagens.

Com o tcomment instalado, você pode fazer, pelo modo Normal:

- `gcc` para comentar/descomentar a linha atual
- `V` para selecionar linhas visualmente, e `gc` para comentar/descomentar as linhas selecionadas
- `gc{movimento}` para descomentar na direção do movimento. Exemplos:

  - `gc3j` comenta a linha atual e as próximas 3 seguintes
  - `gcG` comenta até o fim do arquivo.

Ele tem mais atalhos, mas os dois primeiros são os que uso predominantemente.

Comment: +1 vou testar esse plugin ainda não conhecia, parece muito promissor!

Answer (score 5):

No caso de comentários de uma unica linha uso o seguinte método

Colocar simbolo de comentario no Inicio da linha

1. tecla <kbd>0</kbd> leva-o para o inicio da linha (opcional)
2. teclas <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (fica em visual block)
3. com as teclas direcionais seleciona as linhas a comentar
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (I maiúsculo)
5. Um cursor de escrita vai aparecer na primeira linha selecionada- escrever o simbolo de comentario, i.e. '#' ou '//'
6. selecionar <kbd>ESC</kbd> e as linhas vão ficar todas comentadas

Para remover comentarios do inicio da linha

1. tecla <kbd>0</kbd> leva-o para o inicio da linha (opcional)
2. teclas <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (fica em visual block)
3. com as teclas direcionais seleciona as linhas a descomentar. No caso de serem dois simbolos como em '//' podes usar as teclas direccionais para selecionar uma matriz de NxM
4. Selecionar <kbd>x</kbd> apaga tudo que tiver dentro da matriz

alternativamente para dois simbolos ('//') podes fazer os passos 1, 2 e 3  mas selecionar só o inicio das linhas, de seguida fazer <kbd>x</kbd>(apaga a primeira coluna), <kbd>f</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (seleciona a mesma area de visual block) e depois <kbd>x</kbd>(apaga a segunda coluna)

Para efectuar comentarios multi-linha a lá C (/* coment */) não tenho uma maneira imediata, mas com o metodo acima raramente tenho necessidade de usar comentarios multi-linha

Comment: não sabia, então +1 pelo aprendizado! :)

Comment: +1 gostei bastante da resposta, vou dar mais um tempo pra ver se alguém aparece com uma solução pro multi-linha também, senão vou dar como certa sua solução, pois já resolve 90% dos meus casos :)

Comment: É, seleção vertical ajuda a comentar blocos com comentários de linha. Quando for apenas uma linha, você tbm pode usar `I`, que entra no modo de inserção com o cursor no começo da linha atual. Usei esses métodos por algum tempo, mas hoje prefiro o tcomment.

Answer (score 4):

Eu uso um plugin chamado [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) ele é bem legal e tem atalhos pré-definidos bem faceis de usar, olha só:

- Comentar a linha atual: <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
- Comentar várias linhas: <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>
- Desfaz os comentários: <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>
- Comentar e copiar a linha atual: <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

A tecla <kbd>\</kbd> é a minha tecla ***leader*** que vem definida por padrão mas, você pode mudar usando o comando

```
let mapleader = "_"
```

assim ao invéz de usar <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> você usaria <kbd>_</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, para comentar a linha atual.

Answer (score 1):

Para remover comentários começando em `#`:

```
:%s/\s*#.*//g
```

Para remover comentários começando em `//`:

```
:%s/\s*\/\/.*//g
```

Para remover blocos de comentários cercados por `/*` e `*/`:

```
:%s/\/\*.*\*\///g
```

Comment: Cara é uma boa solução utilizar substituição, mas eu acho que me expressei mal, eu não quero remover todos os comentários do código, quero ser seletivo algumas linhas, para facilmente fazer um toggle, vou editar a pergunta, mas te dei +1

Answer (score 0):

resposta com 1 ano de atraso... **Para comentarios multi-linha a lá C (/* coment */)**

(I) Apagar o conteúdo de um comentário:

1. procurar o *início do comentário*: `/\/\*`
2. remover: `d%`
3. procurar próxima ocorrência de *início de comentário*: `n`
4. remover próxima `.`

(II) Para comentar uma área a lá C (/* coment */):

1. definimos um comando genérico para comentar uma área visual (seja `\q`)
2. marcar visualmente a área
3. comentar a área com `\q`

Para definir o comentador de área visual, definimos um atalho no `.vimrc`

```
:vmap \q di/**/<ESC>hP
```

que no fundo apaga a área (`d`), insere (`i`) `/**/`, e volta a pôr o apagado no meio (`P`).

Answer (score 0):

O mais complicado em minha opinião são os comentários multilinha, se o arquivo tiver muitas linhas ficar fazendo seleção visual vai contra os princípios do vim.

O comando Global nos fornece uma solução elegante para adicionar um caractere nesses trechos (no caso estou colocando `%`)

```
 :g/\/\*\*/,/\*\// s/^/%

 :g .................. comando global
 /\/\*\*/ ............ localiza /**
 , ................... indica intervalo
 /\*\// .............. localiza */
 s/^/%  .............. substitua o começo de linha "^" por "%"
```

Fazendo o inverso

```
 g/%\/\*\*/,/%\*\// s/^%//
```

Adiciona-se "%" nas duas porções do intervalo e a substituição fica:

```
s/^%//
```

Via plugins eu recomendaria o [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) do Tim Pope, é muito eficient.